# Change color of my Wordpress footer to be true black?

Tags: css, wordpress, footer, background-color

I am trying to change the color of my footer - I am using the theme Pique and it forces you to have a background image for the footer, so I had to make a footer.php file for my Pique child theme and upload it. Then I was able to change the background color to black instead of an image.

However, if you take a look at my website, http://blackbottle.com.au/, the footer is a bit off an off-black, almost looks brown. I have it set to the same color as the nav bar which is a deep black when you scroll. I'd love for the footer to be that color. I am stumped at this point - tried editing the php file and css. Any ideas?

Comment: Your footer has a `:before` pseudo-element. That element has a background. Try resetting it like so `.site-footer::before {background: none}`

Comment: Also, look into [firefox dev tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) or [chrome dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) - depending on what you use - if you want to learn how to spot these things on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok from the website what i can see is that the color is being inherited from `style.css line 2000`

just comment out that and you will get the color you need, hope it helps

this is the link to that css

```
http://blackbottle.com.au/wp-content/themes/pique/style.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this in your 'style.css' file.

```
.site-footer::before {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in css file

```
.site-footer::before {
    background: #000;
}
```

In case it not work then you can try this one

```
.site-footer::before {
    background: #000!important;
}
```